# How to convert xml tag with period(.) to jaxb variable

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml like below.

```
<first.name>abc</first.name>
```

When I try to convert it jaxb variable like below

```
@XmlElement (name = "first.name")
private String firstName;
```

It is not capturing the value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a work for me. please refer below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a work for me

xml file (user.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user>
    <first.name>samba</first.name>
</user>
```

class for user (User.java)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User {

    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "first.name")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

unmarshalling

```
File file = new File("user.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
User user = (User) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println("User's Name: "+user.getFirstName())
```

output

```
User's Name: samba
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please modify your POJO class as given below. This should work.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "first.name")
class Pojo {
    @XmlValue
    private String firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a last option, you can replace "first.name" with "firstname"